# Writing in a completion date in a separate cell when the task is marked as complete in a different cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet where one row shows how many % of a task is complete, i want it to write down today's date when that number becomes 100%.

As in:

```
%    |  Date 
--------------
50   |  
100  | 02/02/14    
70   |
```

This should, from what i have read around the web, be possible with Google Apps Script, but I have absolutely no idea how those work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small little snippet will do the trick.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.value == 100) {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/YY");
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Add the code from the menu item *Tools*, followed by *Script editor*. Press the "bug" button and you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a lot of applications create some kinds of events when certain things happen.

You want to detect when a user enters the value of 100% in a cell ... meaning edits a cell and the numeric value becomes 1.

So to get on with your task, familiarize yourself with

- how to write [scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros) in general in Google doc's
- how to use [events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) - in particular the spreadsheet edit event

as you want to create a scripts which reacts on a spreadsheet edit event and check if the value entered into the just edited range equals 1 ... as in this case you want to write the system date into a neighboring cell.

Start to produce some code and come back any time with more questions.